# Azure resource manager template - property loops is not working keep getting error as copyindex is not expected

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy  the Arm template using the properties copy loop as per the documentation available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties for loadbalancer and its not working. Template validation failed error as " language Expression property 'protocol' cant be evaluated.

If I remove loadbalancer rules copy and try iterating the healthprobes property alone its working.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymenttemplate.json#",
"contentversion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
```

.......

```
    "lbprobe": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [
            {
                "name": "customAppPort",
                "frontendPort": "8080",
                "backendPort": "8888",
                "protocolprobe": "tcp",
                "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
                "name": "httpsPort",
                "frontendPort": "443",
                "backendPort": "443",
                "protocolprobe": "tcp",
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }

        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "description"
        }
    }
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {},
 "resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('lbname')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard",
            "tier": "Regional"
        },
        "properties": {
            "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "[parameters('lbfrontendip')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'testvnet-01', 'default')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "backendAddressPools": [
                {
                    "name": "[parameters('lbbackendpool')]"
                }
            ],
            "copy": [
                
                {
                    "name": "loadBalancingRules",
                    "count": "[length(parameters('lbprobe'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].name]",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendipconfiguration": {
                                "id": "[resourceid('microsoft.network/loadbalancers/frontendipconfigurations', parameters('lbname'), parameters('lbfrontendip'))]"
                            },
                            "backendaddresspool": {
                                "id": "[resourceid('microsoft.network/loadbalancers/backendaddresspools', parameters('lbname'), parameters('lbbackendpool'))]"
                            },
                            "protocol": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules').protocol]]",
                            "frontendport": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules').frontendPort]]",
                            "backendport": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules').backendPort]]",
                            "enablefloatingip": false,
                            "idletimeoutinminutes": 5,
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[resourceid('microsoft.network/loadbalancers/probes', parameters('lbname'),parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].name)]"
                            }

                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Probes",
                    "count": "[length(parameters('lbprobe'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('Probes')].name]",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('Probes')].protocolprobe]",
                            "port": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('Probes')].frontendPort]",
                            "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                            "numberOfProbes": 2
                        }
                    }
                }

            ]

        }
    }
],
"outputs": {}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried the same code and can able to reproduce the above issue and identify the root cause.

***Error Details:-***

[image]

**In your template in copy `loadBalancingRules` you are using the below**:

```
"protocol": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules').protocol]]",
                            "frontendport": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules').frontendPort]]",
                            "backendport": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules').backendPort]]",
```

***Instead you should use the below:***

```
"protocol": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].protocol]",
"frontendport": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].frontendPort]",
"backendport": "[parameters('lbprobe')[copyIndex('loadBalancingRules')].backendPort]",
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS:-***

[image]

Comment: I corrected the template and it worked. Thanks a lot for the response.  I was able to deploy when I added the probes copy block in the template without the Load balancing rules.

Comment: I didn't check the loadbalacing rules script block and was only tried to redeploy and debug the rest of the template -- Thanks !

Comment: Glad that it helped! If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: The same template is not working when trying to deploy using the custom deployment in Azure portal [Deploy from a custom template] - Getting error not a valid template.   When deployed using powershell its getting deployed.